# Pop a fixed key - value pair from an associative array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have array structure like this:

```
Main-Array
(
    [0] => Sub-Array
    (
        [0] => AAA
        [1] => BBB
        [2] => -
        [3] => DDD
    )

    [1] => Sub-Array
    (
        [0] => 111
        [1] => 222
        [2] => -
        [3] => 444
    )
)
```

As per the above mentioned example i want to pop **Main-Array[0][2] & Main-Array[1][2]** out of the array as both are empty..

I know to do it by executing a foreach loop and assigning a new array as per requirement..  but if there is a better way or any PHP array function that is i am unaware of.. Then suggestions are welcomed..

Comment: is there a minus sign or empty value in Main-Array[0][2] & Main-Array[1][2] ?

Comment: Check out =  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: i have a possible answer, if you want to try it, i post my ansewer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array_fill = array(array('AAA','BBB','-','DDDD'), array(111,222,'-',444));
function clean_now($var)
{
    return $var == '-'? false: true;    
}

function cleanme($var)
{
    return array_filter($var, "clean_now"); 
}

print_r(array_map("cleanme",$array_fill));
```

Since it's 2 dimensional array, I first use `array_map` to filter the array inside of each array, and `array_filter` to remove `'-'` from the array.

Try to copy my code then run it on your side. I added the variable value.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `unset($index);`   to remove an item from array

note that in above case  index remains unchanged.

else

`array_splice()` can be used if you'd like to normalize your integer keys. Another option is using `array_values()` after `unset()`

Comment: ya.. **unset** will work for me... but for that i will have to loop it again.. but then also its fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($main_arr as &$arr) {
  $arr = array_filter($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a[]=array(DD,AA,'',1);
$a[]=array(mm,er,'',4);
foreach($a as $b)
{
    rsort($b);
    array_pop($b);
    $c[]=$b;
}
print_r($c);
```

since you said both are empty this is one of the easiest way in achieving it 
after that your output will be as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => DD
            [2] => AA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => mm
            [2] => er
        )

)
```